# Using for loop to add 10 numbers

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Write a program that asks the user for 10 numbers and prints out the total. With the help for loop, I need to collect 10 values and add them but. Like in the example below:

Here is a sample run of the program:

```
Please enter a number: 5
Please enter a number: 2015
Please enter a number: -100
Please enter a number: 3
Please enter a number: -999
Please enter a number: 8
Please enter a number: 67
Please enter a number: 19
Please enter a number: 17
Please enter a number: -1234

The total is -199       
=========================================
```

Below is what I have tried so far. However, I'm not sure how to add up all the values collected by the for loop, since the variable num only holds to the last value from the loop

```
def main():
    for n in range(10):
        num=eval(input("number?"))
        total=num
        print(total)

main()
```

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Please show your efforts so far.

Comment: I understand SO is not a code-writing service. If advise can be provided, it will be greatly appreciated. Below is what I have tried so far:                                            def main():
    for n in range(10):
        num=eval(input("number?"))
        total=num
        print(total)

main()

Answer (score 1):

### The previous answer did raise an error:

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
8
9
---> 10 main()

in main()
2     for n in range(10):
3         num =int(input("Please enter a number: "))
----> 4         total += num
5
6     print("The total is " + total)

### UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment

This can be easily fixed by using:

```
def main():
    total = 0
    for n in range(10):
        num =int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        total += num

    print("The total is ", total)
    print("=========================================")
```

---

or how I solved the initial question:

```
def add(itr):
  total = 0
  for n in range(itr):
    num = float(input("number:"))
    total+= num
    print(total)
add(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is quite close. You want to increase the `total` by the `num` each time. You also want to convert the input to an integer using the `int()` function. Additionally, you want the total to be printed only once at the end, so it should be outside of the loop.

```
def main():
    for n in range(10):
        num =int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        total += num

    print("The total is " + total)
    print("=========================================")


main()
```